# Cannot drop trigger getting error in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, syntax-error, sql-drop, postgresql-triggers

I am learning **PostgreSQL** after python. I follow tutorialspoint.com website.

There is no problem until i create a trigger and it works like a charm..

But when I tried to delete (i.e., drop) the trigger, i get the following error.

```
DROP TRIGGER example_trigger;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: DROP TRIGGER example_trigger;
                                    ^
```

I am not sure why do I get this error. Help me please. Is it common or am I going wrong?

Comment: I am using terminal in ubuntu 12.04 OS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptrigger.html), the correct syntax is:

```
drop trigger example_trigger on table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created `my_t` trigger on `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t AFTER UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

Then, I tried to drop `my_t` trigger as shown below:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER my_t;
```

But, I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
> LINE 1: DROP TRIGGER my_t;

So, I set `test` table with `ON` as shown below, then I could drop `my_t` trigger without error. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptrigger.html) explains how to drop a trigger in detail:

```sql
               -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
DROP TRIGGER my_t ON test;
```

In addition, the SQL below with `RESTRICT` is exactly same as the SQL above:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER my_t ON test RESTRICT;
```